# ReactJS - Multiple bundle.js files for each view in PHP

Tags: reactjs

We're attempting to create a PHP Laravel application using ReactJS as the view for each page. Laravel handles the routing and the presenting of each view. Each view loads a react js bundle.js file. Each bundle.js file is custom to that view and inside contains the react components needed for that view (screen). What were finding out is that each bundle.js file is about 4MB because each contain its dependencies as well as the components. Also were still trying to figure out how to share a component such as a TableComponent.js file across multiple views but have been so far unsuccessful.

Are we architecting this totally wrong? Should there always be only one bundle.js file for the application as a whole?

Or are there good fixes to remove the dependencies from each bundle.js file in a single dependency js file that gets loaded for all views?

Is there a good way to reuse ReactJS components accross multiple bundle.js files ?

Comment: What are you using to bundle?

Comment: Yeah we're using gulp with browserify, watchify,babelify, minify to create the  bundle.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect case to use Webpack which is an amazing bundling tool, here is an example on how to build multiple entries(pages):

https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html

You just write your entry point code, and webpack will figure out the details on how to build shared dependencies of different entries(pages) into a common bundle.

Comment: We ended up using gulp with a similar method of using multiple entries to create a single bundle.js file. and we reduced the code of the entire application to about 1.9 MB which is super awesome. There's room to make it smaller by removing some dependencies.

Comment: @jklapwyk care to share your gulp solution?